# Magento Product Images upload not working in my code

Tags: php, magento, csv, magento-1.7

I have below code which should update product images in Magento using product sku from csv file.

In my csv file, there are two columns, First column in Product SKU and second with Image Name.

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);

    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    //Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); 
    define('CSV_PATH','csvfiles/');

    $csv_fileoutput = CSV_PATH . "output_imagesupload.csv";
    $csvfileoutput = fopen($csv_fileoutput, 'a');

    $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'incoming/';
    $file_handle = fopen("csvfiles/images_insert.csv", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $productSKU = $line_of_text[0];
        $productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($productSKU);
        if ($productid) 
        {
            $Products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
            $fileName = $line_of_text[1];
            $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;

            if(file_exists($filePath)) {

                $Products->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
                $Products->save();


            /*  $Products->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath,'image',true,false);
                $Products->save();
*/
    /*  
                $setbaseimage=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($objProduct);
                $setbaseimage->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath,array('image','small_image','thumbnail'),true,false);
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
                $setbaseimage->save();
    */
            } else{
                echo $productSKU . " Not done \n";

            }
                $my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid); 
                $url = $my_product->getProductUrl();

                fputcsv($csvfileoutput, array($productSKU,$url));   
        }
        else {echo $productSKU." - Product is not available\n"; }

    }
    fclose($file_handle);

    ?>
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this for example,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69944/magento-add-image-to-media-gallery-causing-duplicate-images-with-1-appended

```
foreach ($skuImageMap as $sku => $images) {
    $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    $saveFlag = true;
    if ($ourProduct) {
        foreach ($images as $index => $imagePath) {
            if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
                try {
                    $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, null, false, false);
                    $imageCount++;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $saveFlag = false;
                    echo "There was an issue saving image $imagePath to $sku :" . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                }
            } else {
                $saveFlag = false;
                echo "The image $imagePath does not exist.\n";
            }
        }

        if($saveFlag) {
            try {
                $ourProduct->save();
                echo "The image $imagePath was added to $sku successfully : $imageCount \n";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                zend_debug::dump($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo "The product $sku does not exist \n";
    }
}
```